# Scrapy - Scraping different web pages in one scrapy script

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm creating a web app that scrapes a long list of shoes from different websites. 
Here are my two individual scrapy scripts:

http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-clearance-soccer-shoes/47Z7puZ896Zoi3

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request
class ShoesSpider(Spider):
    name = "shoes"
    allowed_domains = ["store.nike.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-clearance-soccer-shoes/47Z7puZ896Zoi3']
    def parse(self, response):
        shoes = response.xpath('//*[@class="grid-item-image-wrapper sprite-sheet sprite-index-0"]/a/@href').extract()
        for shoe in shoes:
            yield Request(shoe, callback=self.parse_shoes)

    def parse_shoes(self, response):
        url = response.url
        name = response.xpath('//*[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract_first()
        price = response.xpath('//*[@itemprop="price"]/text()').extract_first()
        price = price.replace('$','')
        shoe_type =  response.css('.exp-product-subtitle::text').extract_first()

        sizes = response.xpath('//*[@class="nsg-form--drop-down exp-pdp-size-dropdown exp-pdp-dropdown two-column-dropdown"]/option')
        sizes = sizes.xpath('text()[not(parent::option/@class="exp-pdp-size-not-in-stock selectBox-disabled")]').extract()
        sizes = [s.strip() for s in sizes]
        yield {
            'url': url,
            'name' : name,
            'price' : price,
            'sizes' : sizes,
            'shoe_type': shoe_type
        }
```

http://www.dickssportinggoods.com/products/clearance-soccer-cleats.jsp

```
    from scrapy import Spider
    from scrapy.http import Request
    class ShoesSpider(Spider):
        name = "shoes"
        allowed_domains = ["dickssportinggoods.com"]
        start_urls = ['http://www.dickssportinggoods.com/products/clearance-soccer-cleats.jsp']
        def parse(self, response):
            shoes = response.xpath('//*[@class="fplpTitle header4"]/a/@href').extract()
            for shoe in shoes:
                yield Request(shoe, callback=self.parse_shoes)
        def parse_shoes(self, response):
            sizes = response.xpath('//*[@class="swatches clearfix"]/input/@value').extract()
            if sizes == []:
                pass
            url = response.url
            name = response.xpath('.//*[@id="PageHeading_3074457345618261107"]/h1/text()').extract_first()
            price = response.xpath('.//*[@itemprop="price"]/text()').extract_first()
            #shoe_type =  response.css('.exp-product-subtitle::text').extract_first()
            yield {
                    'url': url,
                    'name' : name,
                    'price' : price,
                    'sizes' : sizes,
                    'shoe_type': ''
                }
```

How can I manage to put both of them together? I already went through the scrapy documentation and I haven't seen them mentioning this, it just mentions how to scrape two addresses from a root address. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your both domains in `allowed_domains` and put your both URLs in `start_urls` and then use simple if-else to determine what part of code to execute.

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request
class ShoesSpider(Spider):
    name = "shoes"
    allowed_domains = ["store.nike.com", "dickssportinggoods.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-clearance-soccer-shoes/47Z7puZ896Zoi3', 'http://www.dickssportinggoods.com/products/clearance-soccer-cleats.jsp']
    def parse(self, response):

        if "store.nike.com" in response.url:
            shoes = response.xpath('//*[@class="grid-item-image-wrapper sprite-sheet sprite-index-0"]/a/@href').extract()
        elif "dickssportinggoods.com" in response.url:
            shoes = response.xpath('//*[@class="fplpTitle header4"]/a/@href').extract()

        for shoe in shoes:
            yield Request(shoe, callback=self.parse_shoes)

    def parse_shoes(self, response):
        url = response.url

        if "store.nike.com" in response.url:
            name = response.xpath('//*[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract_first()
            price = response.xpath('//*[@itemprop="price"]/text()').extract_first()
            price = price.replace('$','')
            shoe_type =  response.css('.exp-product-subtitle::text').extract_first()

            sizes = response.xpath('//*[@class="nsg-form--drop-down exp-pdp-size-dropdown exp-pdp-dropdown two-column-dropdown"]/option')
            sizes = sizes.xpath('text()[not(parent::option/@class="exp-pdp-size-not-in-stock selectBox-disabled")]').extract()
            sizes = [s.strip() for s in sizes]
            yield {
                'url': url,
                'name' : name,
                'price' : price,
                'sizes' : sizes,
                'shoe_type': shoe_type
            }
        elif "dickssportinggoods.com" in response.url:
                sizes = response.xpath('//*[@class="swatches clearfix"]/input/@value').extract()
                if sizes == []:
                    pass
                url = response.url
                name = response.xpath('.//*[@id="PageHeading_3074457345618261107"]/h1/text()').extract_first()
                price = response.xpath('.//*[@itemprop="price"]/text()').extract_first()
                #shoe_type =  response.css('.exp-product-subtitle::text').extract_first()

                yield {
                        'url': url,
                        'name' : name,
                        'price' : price,
                        'sizes' : sizes,
                        'shoe_type': ''
                }
```

Comment: @tadm123 GREAT!. I did not run your code, if my code had any syntax error or any other issue, please edit my answer with your fully working code so it might help future readers/

Comment: Just the `ellif` but you fixed it now. Thanks for laying out how to do it, I have like 10 different scripts of shoes trying to tie all of them together.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify allowed_domains variable.
You can ignore allowed_domains variable so you don't have domain limitation.