# Scraping products data with categories from e-commerce

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, e-commerce, screen-scraping

I need to develop an application that takes as input an url of an e-commerce website and scrap the products titles, prices with the categories and sub-categories.

Scrapy seems like a good solution for scraping data, so my question is how can I tell scrapy where the titles, prices, cat and sub categories are to extract them knowing that websites have different structures and don't really use the same tags?

EDIT: I gotta change my question to this, can't we write a generic spider that takes the start url, allowed domains, and xpath or css selectors as arguments?

Comment: `how can i tell scrapy where the titles, prices, cat and sub categories are to extract them knowing that websites have different structures` Its impossible bro ... scraping is done by parsing HTML tags of a website or JSON responses ... you can not build a general scraper to work across websites having different HTML structure ...

Comment: That's what i thought as well, but that's what they're asking me to do, so any ideas are welcome, thank you bro

Comment: Bro I have 4 years of experience in scraping, I think its impossible ... But if you already know which websites you want to scrape ... this answer might help ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/42637648/4094231

Comment: Maybe with some machine learning it could work?

Comment: Scraping is also some sort of machine learning,

Answer (score -1):

Categories and subcategories are usually in the breadcrumbs.

In general the css selector for those will be `.breadcrumb a` and that will probably work for 80% of modern e-commerce websites.